# How to solve $\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin(2x)}{e^x} dx$?

Tags: integration

I am stuck at this integral. Can anybody help or give me a hint what to do? I have tried to use integration by parts but keep getting stuck.

$$\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin(2x)}{e^x}dx$$

Comment: Please `\sin`, don’t sin.

Comment: Integration by parts, or use $\sin(2x)=(e^{2ix}-e^{-2ix})/2i$

Comment: What is wrong with integration by parts ?

Comment: I don't see this as a duplicate, for two reasons: this one is a definite integral, and the coefficient of the sine not being unity makes some of the solutions a little less immediate.

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{\sin(2x)}{e^x}$$ is the imaginary part of

$$e^{(-1+2i)x},$$

that integrates as

$$\left.\frac{e^{(-1+2i)x}}{-1+2i}\right|_0^\infty=-\frac1{-1+2i}=\frac{1+2i}5.$$

Comment: I do not know much about integrating complex functions, but this answer looks nice. Why is the downvote?

Comment: @VIVID: integrating $e^{(a+bi)x}$ is formally equivalent to simultaneous integration of $e^{ax}\cos(bx)$ and $e^{ax}\sin(bx)$ in terms of themselves, and is just a way of condensing the computation. There is no deep magic, and for the same price you get the cosine integral. Presumably by development was too terse. Thanks for your support :)

Answer (score 1):

Write it as

$$\int_0^{+\infty} e^{-x}\sin(2x)\ \text{d}x$$

Integrate by parts getting

$$-\dfrac{1}{2}e^{-x}\cos(2x)\bigg|_0^{+\infty} - \dfrac{1}{2}\int_0^{+\infty} e^{-x}\cos(2)\ \text{d}x$$

The first numerical term goest to $-\dfrac{1}{2}$

Integrate by parts again the second integral to get

$$\dfrac{1}{2}\left(\dfrac{1}{2}e^{-x}\sin(2x) - \int_0^{+\infty} \dfrac{1}{2}e^{-x}\sin(2x)\ \text{d}x\right)$$

The numerical term goest to zero and you are left with

$$\int_0^{+\infty} e^{-x}\sin(2x)\ \text{d}x = \dfrac{1}{2} - \dfrac{1}{4} \int_0^{+\infty} e^{-x}\sin(2x)\ \text{d}x $$

The two integrals are identical but opposite signs. Arrange and you will get:

$$\int_0^{+\infty} e^{-x}\sin(2x)\ \text{d}x = \dfrac{2}{5}$$

Answer (score 1):

Since the integral consists of two transcendental functions $\sin(2x)$ and $e^{-x}$, you may use integration by parts. Set $u = \sin(2x)$ and $dv = e^{-x}dx$ and we get
$$
\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^{\infty} \sin(2x)e^{-x}dx &= \left[-\sin(2x)e^{-x} \right|_{0}^{\infty} + 2\int_{0}^{\infty}\cos(2x)e^{-x}dx \\
&= 2\int_{0}^{\infty}\cos(2x)e^{-x}dx
\end{align*}
$$
Doing integration by parts again with $u = \cos(2x)$ and $dv = e^{-x}dx$ we have
$$
\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^{\infty} \cos(2x)e^{-x}dx &= \left[-\cos(2x)e^{-x} \right|_{0}^{\infty} - 2\int_{0}^{\infty}\sin(2x)e^{-x}dx \\
&= 1-2\int_{0}^{\infty}\sin(2x)e^{-x}dx.
\end{align*}
$$
Putting everything together we obtain
$$\int_{0}^{\infty} \sin(2x)e^{-x}dx = 2 - 4 \int_{0}^{\infty} \sin(2x)e^{-x}dx$$
Setting $y = \int_{0}^{\infty} \sin(2x)e^{-x}dx$ we then need to solve
$$y = 2 - 4y \Rightarrow 5y = 2 \Rightarrow y = \int_{0}^{\infty} \sin(2x)e^{-x}dx = 2/5.$$